# AngularJs filter "Error while interpolating"

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Inside my AngularJs filter I have the following:

```
 return function(list){
      return list;
 }
```

That works fine

However, the following throws an error of "Error while interpolating {{ list | filterName}}...TypeError: list is undefined"

```
 return function(list){
      return list.length;
 }
```

What is happening that is causing list to be undefined for a brief moment when this function runs, or what can I do to fix this issue. The value still gets returned, I just have a nasty error in console.

Comment: it happens when angularJs is bootstrapping the page, for a brief moment (between the moment it starts and the moment it actually reaches this part of your page) the value will be undefined, you can simply do `if(typeof(list) != undefined){return list.length;}`

Answer (score 2):

**DotDotDot** already answered question, but I'd like to improve his answer:

```
return function(list){
    return (typeof(list) !== 'undefined') ? list.length : 0;
}
```

Update for Angular users:

```
return function(list){
    return angular.isDefined(list) ? list.length : 0;
}
```