# Use a custom function from an angular template

Tags: angularjs, templates

I'm displaying urls from an angular template, but I'd like to 'slugify' it, that is, replace those ugly chars. Right now I just want to replace spaces with '_'.

This is the code I have on my index.html file

```
<a ng-href="#/{{url}}">{{name}}</a>
```

I'd like to define a slugify function like this:

```
slugify = function(url) {
  return url.replace(' ', '_');
};
```

And then being able to call it from every the template like this

```
<a ng-href="#/{{slugify(url)}}">{{name}}</a>
```

How could I achieve it?

-- edit

I finally went with @underscore solution (added it to the $rootScope) and from a normal controller it works ok. But from a template inside the ng-app directive, but with no ng-controller, it works too, but it gives me the following error, lots of times:

```
Error: error:interr
Interpolation Error
Can't interpolate: #/{{slug(b.link)}}
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

This is the offending code:

```
<a ng-show='b.link' ng-href="#/{{slug(b.link)}}">{{b.name}}</a>
```

I tried with regular href and ng-href, and also with $root.slug, but it always throws the same error a dozen times, nevertheless it works ok.

Also tried defining a filter, like Peter said, and it gave me the same error:

```
Can't interpolate: #/{{b.link | slug}}
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Nevertheless, it worked ok too...

--

ok, final edit

It seems when angular is bootstraping the input value might be undefined (as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18573426/47633)

I could solve the nasty error message with:

```
presuApp.filter('slug', function() {
  return function(input) {
    return input ? input.replace(/ /g, '_') : '';
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a function in your controller e.g.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.theInput = 'example input';
   $scope.slugify = function(input) {
       input = input.replace(' ', '_');
       return input;
   }
});
```

Here's a plunkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/RARhGQzQoGPtWhoFColL?p=preview

A more correct way might be to use a filter:

```
app.filter('slugify', function() {
  return function(input) {
    input = input.replace(' ', '_');
    return input
  }
})
```

And in the template you put:

```
using a filter:
{{ theInput | slugify }}
```

Also added that to plunkr

Comment: Agree with "Peter Ashwell", it is the better and efficient way if it is defined in a filter. Then you'd be able to use in anywhere, you'll just need to inject that using Dependency injection

Comment: I finally chose this solution, but I had to check on input being defined because of angular bootstraping, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18573426/47633

Answer (score 1):

> "And then being able to call it from every the template like this"

In this case you should use `$rootScope` instead of controller scope.

just use it in the `$rootScope`

```
$rootScope.slugify = function(url) {
  return url.replace(' ', '_');
};
```

Define it in the `app.run();` . So the function will define when angular bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

In your controller you can bind $scope to a function to make it accessible via the html.

```
$scope.slugify = function(url) {
  return url.replace(' ', '_');
};
```